# How to measure the running time of a java program which is already a .class file

Tags: java

I want to measure the performance of a program which is compiled into a .class file. I do not access to the code to add stopwatch methods to it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can:

- use a profiler
- call this Java code from another class, which you can write. You can access Java methods inside `.class` file without having the source code
- decompile the `.class` file, inject watches and compile back
- use compile- or load-time weaver and AOP to weave watches to existing classes (essentially does the same thing as above)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Java profiler like the one called JVisualVM that comes with the Java distribution.

Answer (score 0):

On a Unix/Linux system, you can try the `time` command.

```
time java myClassFile
```

Answer (score 0):

This class is like a program or library?

1. LIBRARY: get `System.nanoTime` or `System.currentTimeMillis` before creation or runing method for this class and after that. Math substraction can you tell how long it's take.
2. PROGRAM/LIBRARY: You can decompile this class and put instructions to measurement time (as above)
3. PROGRAM: you can use JAMON API
4. PROGRAM (for example SPRING): Use AOP method to put instruction before creating object and after deconstruction.